How many types of tRNA are there in a human cell?
If the genetic codon on mRNA is a triplet then this means the four bases (A, T, G and C) can have 64 possible combinations. But since three of these codons are non-sense (non-coding) so we are left with 61 codons.
So this means there should be 61 types of tRNA bearing anticodons complementary to these 61 codons? Since I've read that there are no tRNA having anticodons complementary to these stops codons.
Also why does a quick google search tells you there are 20 types of tRNA? Is this completely wrong?

Welcome to SE Biology. Please do us the courtesy of finishing the [Tour] and then read the Help on asking good questions. You will see that you are expected to "thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question". It is clear from your question that you have never consulted even an introductory text on biochemistry or molecular biology on the topic of translation. You need to do so as your suppositions, conclusions and the results of your Google search are incorrect. The topic has a greater complexity than you imagine, and is too broad for an answer here.
